# .NET Blazor and client-side debugging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is Blazor client-side debugging possible or what is that experience like?

Blazor is new to me. I've used Razor / MVC significantly in the past but moved on to other technologies. Checking it out now, Blazor is definitely an improvement and seems to replace Javascript with dot NET. One of the things mentioned is it can run on the browser. My question then is: how is the client-side debugging experience in Dev Chrome Tools?

One of the Blazor videos in checking out:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0c7d64W-B8&list=PLcYfGPOcgilkwLcDgXrOoqvTd-2ettqED

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your browser's developer tools aren't going to be particularly useful when debugging Blazor apps. Here are the types of messages you'll see in the console.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools with Blazor app running]

The code running the browser is WebAssembly, compiled from C# or other .NET language. WebAssembly is binary, so you're not going to be able to debug that in your browser. Instead, you'd want to debug the .NET language in an IDE (Visual Studio, VS Code, etc.).

Comment: You can actually use the browser debug tools to step through .NET code,  but you are right in that the experience is better in visual studio.